# Do all fundamental frequencies have 1 anti-node and 2 nodes

Tags: theory, acoustics, pitch

Given any musical instrument, when a note is played on the instrument, does the **fundamental** have only one **node** and 2 **antinodes** (Theoretically fundamental frequencies should have half wavelength)? If yes what  factor in the instrument allows it to create such a wave(like length of string )?

Comment: Since you mentioned a string, with the ends fixed that's already at least 2 nodes for any vibration mode.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_frequency has a diagram for a string.  (And links to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(music)#Frequencies,_wavelengths,_and_musical_intervals_in_example_systems for more about string harmonics)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, no. If you take a tube, closed at both ends (or opened at both ends, depending if you are talking about nodes of pressure, or nodes of displacements), the fundamental will indeed have an anti-node and two nodes.

However, there are instruments which are making the sound from tubes closed at one end (the organ for instance). In that case, the [fundamental frequency will have one node, and one anti-node.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_resonance#Closed_at_one_end)

Comment: Exactly the example I was going to cite.  You could also include bells, plates, and other 2D vibrating systems, or stiff bars with various boundary conditions. You may also want to mention that for the half closed tube the fundamental wavelength is 4*L.

Comment: @ggcg Yes, there are a lot of examples! I wanted to keep it short however, and answer "only" the: "Do all fundamental frequencies have 1 anti-node and 2 nodes", No. Bells are also a great example I agree, but it is more complicated to describe what is happening in there!

Comment: @Tom Oh! That was very informative. But there is one thing that bothers me. When a pitch is played in any instrument we also hear overtones. Eg . when a C note is played , we hear overtones lets say G . Then G has more than one anti-nodes . Then is G a fundamental?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @hanceldsouza yes, overtones will have more antinodes, but there are not the fundamental, there are overtones/harmonics: their frequency is usually a multiple of the fundamental. I suggest reading the whole wiki article I linked, schemes are good and it's pretty complete :). Overtones are treated also!

Comment: @hanceldsouza an overtone would be expected to have more nodes and anti-nodes than the fundamental. The fundamental will generally be the longest/simplest waveform that can be established in the resonator.

Comment: Yep.  I'd just add that the distinction "fundamental" versus "overtone" is artificial: there are only various resonances going from low to high.  It's mathematically and physically preferable to refer to "first harmonic" (fundamental), "second harmonic" (first overtone), etc.

Comment: @hanceldsouza, I think you are confusing the individual harmonics supported by the string or pipe with the complex wave formed by exciting it.  The question is asking about the individual modes. (I see you asked the question, so perhaps with this new info you can reformulate it)

Comment: @ggcg , Yes it could be that. When you pluck lowest string E(82 Hz)  on a guitar it will vibrate at fundamental and harmonics frequencies in which one harmonic would be pitch A(246 Hz). I was just thinking if the next string A  can vibrate only at harmonic A frequency 246 Hz  ( not fundamental A( 110.00 Hz)  . Then A string should be be same as E i.e. the fundamental would be still E ) which may be impossible. 
In simple you can play open E on E but can you play open A on E ? . It may sound like a stupid question.

Comment: I cleared all my confusions!! :)